# Pre-loading sound files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Hope someone can help, this is driving me mad...

I am working on an intranet application where I need to preload a large number (106!) MP3 files. I'm pre-loading these like so...

```
for (i=0; i<mp3Files.length; i++) {

    soundSpan = document.createElement("span")

    soundFileLocation = "http://wss/sites/TDABQ/" + mp3Files[i]

    soundSpan.innerHTML="<embed src='" + soundFileLocation + "' hidden='true' autostart='false' loop='false' />"

    document.body.appendChild(soundSpan)
}
```

This works but takes a little while, however tardy loading is not the problem.

The problem is I cannot figure out a way to determine when all the files have loaded so that I can prompt the user the page is ready.

Issues:

1. This has to work on Internet Explorer 6 (yes, really) so that rules out HTML5 / Audio
2. I cannot load anything onto the server where this application is stored (don't ask) which has so far ruled out SoundManager. I can get SoundManager to work fine when it's on the same server as the application but trying to load SoundManager from another server causes problems with the Flash > JS (or is it JS > Flash) security settings. Those settings cannot be changed on client PCs.
3. I've tried using JQuery's Ajax and Get methods but for some reason cannot get it to do Ajax calls cross domain e.g. the following code never displays the alert box

   $(document).ready(function() {

   $.get({ url: "http://wss/sites/TDABQ/field1.mp3", crossDomain:true, success: function() { alert('yes!')  }     });

   });

Hence i'm using Embed tags to do the pre-loading. Embed tags do not seem to respond to onLoad or onReadyStateChange event handlers.

I've run out of ideas...

How do I find out when all the files have loaded???

Comment: Have you set [crossdomain.xml](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) for SoundManager?

Comment: @Esailija I'm sorry but I am not familiar with crossdomain.xml. Do I place a file called crossdomain.xml in the root of the server that contains the SoundManager files or the root of the server that contains the web pages that use SoundManager?

Comment: @user1555329 You would place it where you are trying to retrieve the mp3 files from. Here's more info http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html Have you also set `allowScriptAccess="always"` on the html for the flash?

Comment: @11684 I didn't think you could apply JQuery's .ready method to individual objects, I thought it just fired when DOM ready occured. Anyway, I tried it and it always seems to execute code even for Embed objects that don't exist!

Comment: @user1555329 you can't, it will be same as dom ready. `$(anything).ready` will always just be DOM ready. And that's just for the document jQuery is loaded in. You cannot even pass it a different document. Your best bet is to get the flash working since embed elements don't support onload. You could google for SoundManager cross domain issues since it's a pretty popular library. I am going to bed.

Comment: @Esailija The Adobe specs were heavy going (!) but I found http://www.crossdomainmaker.com which makes creating crossdomain.xml files a LOT easier :-)

Comment: @user1555329 I was just curious!

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is not working because (for cross-domain AJAX) a JSONP request is the only request allowed to be made. The current example is not requesting JSON, but an mp3. You could request a JSON file that has the paths to the .mp3s, but that's not going to solve your issue.

I don't know about the inner workings of Sound Manager. I would follow Esailija's advice and check the crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0):

Ty using

```
$("#yourEmbed").bind('load', function(){ 
  alert("Files loaded"); 
});
```

The ready handler wont work, as it is fired as soon as the DOM has fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid the code seems to do nothing at all. I cannot get EMBED tags to fire the onLoad event either using normal javascript/DOM or using JQuery.